# Flutter requests using proxy

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy, dio

I need to send requests to server using different proxy and I have list of proxies like ['IP:port:login:password', etc.]
Now I'm using Dio to get/post requests. How can I set proxies to Dio and change them when I want to?

I want to do something like this:
Set 1st proxy > send request > get response (or smth else) > set 2nd proxy > send request > ... (this is an example of course)

Sorry for my English, I'm the Korean student who needs help :)

Dio has proxy_adapter but I think it's not my way. Have no ideas what to do and how to find information :(

Comment: I forgot to add that I will run it on windows, not Android or ios

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem? Have you tried setting the proxy variables in VSCode or in your system variables (Windows).